# Force extjs combo box to have a minimum of one item?

Tags: javascript, select, extjs, combobox

I was wondering if it was possible to force a combo box in Ext JS to have a minimum of one item.

```
 {
      xtype: 'combo',
      id: jobID + "combobox_nodes",
      fieldLabel: 'Running Across Nodes',
      store: Ext.getStore("NodeStore"),
      displayField: "NodeName",
      multiSelect: true,
      valueField: "NodeID",
      queryMode: "local",
      listeners: {
           change: function(combo, record, index) {
                 nodesForJobChanged(jobDetails, tab, combo, record);
           }
      } 
 }
```

Otherwise, I need to implement a catch in my function that checks if there is nothing selected, then if so, it needs to find what WAS selected, and then place that back in programatically - I feel there should be an easier way. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have data in the store (values in the combobox)? You should be able to select a default item when you render then force the selection of the real selection. http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-forceSelection

Comment: This seems to disable the user from being able to enter their own text, but it doesn't do what I was hoping - not allow the user to deselect all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are performing form validation.?
Look at setting `allowBlank: false` and `forceSelection:true`

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up using. It's unfortunate there wasn't an option to just force the user to not be able to deselect the last option, but this works in the end.